# Keep the RegExp search value and add

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

How do I return the value I searched for in RegExp and then add my modifier?
For example the following RegExpression will search for any word between the comma's.

```
[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*
```

The following is my input:

```
Biscuit, Pudding, Pizza, Beans
```

However I can't find a way to add a word like "Cheese-" to those words. The expected output would be:

```
Cheese-Biscuit, Cheese-Pudding, Cheese-Pizza, Cheese-Beans
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear ! What do you mean by "modifier" ? The word modifier [has a meaning in regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html). Aside from that, what language are you using ? You might as well *split* by `\s*,\s*`. It would be helpful if you added the expected output.

Comment: I would like to add a word to the value (which is anything e.g. wildcard) I search for. I want modify the final value so my list becomes "Cheese-Biscuit, Cheese-Pudding, Cheese-Pizza, Cheese-Beans. Using RegExp in Notpad+ List is about 1,000 items so manually would NOT be preferred. Thanks.

Comment: @Greg What _language_ is this in?

Comment: @RyanCarlson Notepad++, check their [regex manual](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update-you have changed to say notepad++. I will leave in case useful to someone else.*

Assuming Javascript (since you mention RegExp):

```
var str = "Biscuit, Pudding, Pizza, Beans";
var patt1 = /[^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*/g;
var result = str.replace(patt1,"Cheese-" + "$&");
```

Output:

> Cheese-Biscuit, Cheese-Pudding, Cheese-Pizza, Cheese-Beans

$& inserts the matched substring.

/g does global match - all matched words.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `CTRL+H` in Notepad++, in replace window **search mode** block, check **Regular Expression**.
then in **Find what** field type : `([^,\s][^\,]*[^,\s]*)` and in **Replace with** field type: `Cheese-\1` then replace all, you'll see this result:

```
Cheese-Biscuit, Cheese-Pudding, Cheese-Pizza, Cheese-Beans
```

[image]

Comment: Without groups, you could use `$0` :)

Comment: @HamZa It's for the sake of clarity